# How do I select the specific row?

Tags: php

I have a variable number of pages and rows, I want the 1st page to show id 1 (first row) of values, 2nd page to show id 2 (second row), etc.

I've two tables, first I have to get the details of the correct "routeid", which is what im trying to do in the prepare statement. But I can't figure out how to select the specific row (row 1 in this case, this is the first page) in the table "detailsroutes".

Edit: Right now it shows the last row of "detailsroutes", and for the images (not shown in this code) it shows all of the images. I want it to only show one row.

I do not have a good basic knowledge of php (or any language really), this is me reverse engineering an example I got.

I've tried putting 2 selects in the prepare statement, tried using UNION between the 2 selects, always got error messages.

this is the code (i didnt include the full html):

```php
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("select routeS, routeD, level, duration, dist, arrival, id, imagepath, routedirections, routedistance from routetb, detailsroutes where routetb.routeid = detailsroutes.routeid;");
         //'where routetb.routeid = detailsroutes.routeid' matches the route to the respective details
        $stmt->bind_result($routeS, $routeD, $level, $duration, $dist, $arrival, $id, $imagepath, $routedirections, $routedistance);
        
        $stmt->execute();
        //" " php will check for variables in the string '' will not check for variables
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo "
            <div class='direction-guide'>
            <div class='direction-guide-wrapper'>
                <div id='direction-arrows'><img></div>
                <div class='direction-description'>
                    <p class='direction-guide-text'>$routedirections</p>
                    <p class='direction-guide-distance'>$routedistance m</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    } 
      
  
    
   ?>
```

the two tables in the database:
["detailsroutes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6aor.png)

["routetb"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRhwQ.png)

Comment: select routeS, routeD, level, duration, dist, arrival, id, imagepath, routedirections, routedistance from routetb INNER JOIN detailsroutes ON (detailsroutes.routeid = routetb.routeid) where routetb.routeid = detailsroutes.routeid

Comment: Instead of INNER JOIN, try with LEFT or RIGHT JOIN for desired results

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp to learn about joins in sql